# Como consumir un servicio Web por metodo POST con HttpWebRquest c#?

Tags: c#

Quiero consumir un servicio web que solicita token y en el body un elemento json , todo esto utilizando codigo c#. En postman funciona correctamente e incluso he tratado de replicar los headers tal cual pero aun no logro que funcione.

He intentado de muchas maneras pero siempre recibo el error: Error en el servidor remoto: (400) Solicitud incorrecta.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
 private string EnviarDocumento(string jsonFirmado, string token)
    {
        string json = "";
        
        try
        {

            //Crear mi objeto
                    var myData = new
                    {
                        peticion = jsonFirmado
                    };

            //Transformacion a json
            string jsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myData);
            var dataL = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonBody);

            var url = "https://apitest.dtes.mh.gob.sv/fesv/recepciondte";
            var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpRequest.Method = "POST";

            httpRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = token;
            httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpRequest.ContentLength = dataL.Length;
            httpRequest.UserAgent = "SAGRISA-WS-Client";

            var data = jsonBody;

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(data);
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                json = result.ToString();
            }               

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            json = "Error: " + exc.Message;
        }
        return json;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

estas seguro de enviar correctamente el Token, debes incluir el token, algo asi (incluso el Bearer):

Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIwMjEwMzAwMzA5MTAyNCIsImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjpbIlVTRVIiLCJVU0VSX0FQSSIsIlVzdWFyaW8iXSwiaWF0IjoxNjgyMjIwNzg0LCJleHAiOjE2ODIzMDcxODR9.SE6hBnjojP_wDJ3RX8fbBt4jXQNZWK2bap4rl91cEwxUFBo_9WT50PV6Wg9hd4LrnH2ISea0CX4KY7oYXtSaDw